# Smooth-filtering image border to create circular image (fourier preparation)

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, filtering, convolution

I learned how to do it yet couldn't remember now, and am failing to get something useful by searching. I have an image, and would like to use this image to create a larger image of size 3x3 by simply stacking them. The border had to be smoothed so that right edge of the image translates seamlessly to the left edge of the image.

[image]

Applying convolutional filter should be able to do it as it deems the image as circular, but how exactly should we do it? We could speak Matlab (or any other language you are comfortable speaking/typing).

EDIT 1:
I prefer only applying the filter to the border, while preserving the original image as much as possible.

EDIT 2:
I tried a gaussian filter. While it blurs the whole image, the edges became more salient compared to the blurry middle. 
`imshow(repmat(imfilter(imread('un1vY.jpg'), fspecial('gaussian',64,8), 'circular'), [3 3]))`

[image]

Comment: What is a constitutional filter?

Comment: spell-check... convolutional

Comment: I think you're talking about `convolve2d` in Python with `boundary='wrap'` or `imfilter` in MATLAB with `circular`.

Comment: @beaker So, if I use `imfilter` in MATLAB, how am I going to only apply the filter at the edge areas but not the middle part of the image? And what is the recommended filter kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full 3x3 sample:

```
function Test()
    close all
    I = imread('un1vY.jpg');
    I = double(I)/255;      %Convert uint8 to double    

    J = HorizFuse(I);

    Jtag = cat(3, J(:,:,1)', J(:,:,2)', J(:,:,3)'); %Transpose across 2'nd dimension.

    K = HorizFuse(Jtag);

    K = cat(3, K(:,:,1)', K(:,:,2)', K(:,:,3)');  %Transpose back

    K = uint8(K*255); %Convert back to uint8
    figure;imshow(K);

    imwrite(K, 'K.jpg');    
end


function K = HorizFuse(I)
    h = linspace(0,1,100);  %Create ramp from 0 to 1 of 100 elements.

    im_w = size(I, 2); %Image width
    im_h = size(I, 1); %Image height

    Hy = repmat(h, [size(I, 1), 1, 3]); %Replicate h to fit image height.

    J = zeros(im_h, im_w*2-100, 3);
    J(:, 1:im_w-100, :) = I(:, 1:im_w-100, :); %Fill pixels from the left to overlap.
    J(:, im_w+1:end, :) = I(:, 101:end, :);    %Fill pixels from the right of overlap.

    %Fill overlap with linear intepolation between right side of left image and left side of right image.
    J(:, im_w-99:im_w, :) = I(:, end-99:end, :).*(1-Hy) + I(:, 1:100, :).*Hy;

    K = zeros(im_h, im_w*3-100*2, 3);
    K(1:size(J,1), 1:size(J,2), :) = J;
    K(1:size(J,1), end-(im_w+100)+1:end, :) = J(1:size(J,1), end-(im_w+100)+1:end, :);
end
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Nice! The program was also elegant. However, as I tried to crop out the central image by 1/3 and 2/3 midpoints so that I could use that as a base to indefinitely generate grids of size nxn (`repmat(base, [n n])`), the edge left a thin trace. Is that systematic in the algorithm, or because of some mistake in cropping?

Comment: Try this: `centerK = K(1+size(I,1)-100:(size(I,1)-100)*2, 1+size(I,2)-100:(size(I,2)-100)*2, :);R = repmat(centerK, [7, 7]);figure;imshow(R);`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution:
Leave some overlapping area between two attached images.
Do linear interpolation between two images in the overlapped area.
Linear interpolation: h*A + (1-h)*B when h goes from 0 to 1.

Illustration of h (replicated to create an image) for attach images horizontally:
[image]

I took 100 pixels wide overlap.
The following code attaches two images horizontally:

```
I = imread('un1vY.jpg');
I = double(I)/255;      %Convert uint8 to double
h = linspace(0,1,100);  %Create ramp from 0 to 1 of 100 elements.

im_w = size(I, 2); %Image width
im_h = size(I, 1); %Image height

Hy = repmat(h, [size(I, 1), 1, 3]); %Replicate h to fit image height.

J = zeros(im_h, im_w*2-100, 3);
J(:, 1:im_w-100, :) = I(:, 1:im_w-100, :); %Fill pixels from the left to overlap.
J(:, im_w+1:end, :) = I(:, 101:end, :);    %Fill pixels from the right of overlap.

%Fill overlap with linear intepolation between right side of left image and left side of right image.
J(:, im_w-99:im_w, :) = I(:, end-99:end, :).*(1-Hy) + I(:, 1:100, :).*Hy;

J = uint8(J*255); %Convert back to uint8
```

This is not the perfect solution, and not a complete one.
Sorry, but I leave you (or another SO user) to finish the work.

Result:
[image]

Comment: The result of it seems much better; I could crop out the shrinked image from the h/2 point. However, since I was concerned with the 3x3 grid, I guess I should make more grids for the interpolation. However, a simple linear interpolation seems to fail if we consider a corner. Consider top-left corner: in a 3x3 grid, the top-left corner of the middle image (2,2) has to be interpolated with (1,1), (2,1) and (1,2) these 3 images, so a method that could handle more than 2 overlap areas is needed.